# Undefined index: method in drupal_prepare_form()

Tags: forms

I am getting this strange notice

> Undefined index: method in drupal_prepare_form()

in my Drupal 7 application but only on production server. It is really weird, on my development PC I have PHP 5.4.6 and on my server I have 5.3.3 and this is probably the only difference. I cannot get this error on my dev PC, so I really don't have any idea what is wrong and how to repair this.

I couldn't find anything good on the web, only that it could be connected with localization modules.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I hope, this can be useful, to you

http://drupal.org/node/1024298

Probably, there is new patch introduced, please go through the blog above.

Comment: I found it:) it was the creation of new form. For php 5.3.3. you have to use $form_sate = form_state_defaults() instead of array(). Thanks anyway!